# How to highlight the edge of a graph via selection in Altair

Tags: python, selection, altair, brush

I am working on selecting edges of a graph using Altair. The idea is to select one or more nodes and draw all the edges that arrive or leave that node. I modeled the code below (minimum working example) after the airport connection example at https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/airport_connections.html  . However, when I run my code, only the edges that *emanate* from the selected node are diplayed rather than all the edges. How would I modify my code to solve this problem. Thank you for any insight you might provide. Gordon.

Code and files can be found at: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rqQdrLAsATSqjWYCvf372SDVt5hTlC9s?usp=sharing

```py
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
import streamlit as st

def drawPlot(node_df, edge_df):

    node_brush = alt.selection_interval(empty='all')

    xscale = alt.Scale(domain=[0, 127])
    yscale = alt.Scale(domain=[0.,410])

    lookup_data = alt.LookupData(
        node_df, key="id", fields=["x", "y"]
    )

    nodes = alt.Chart(node_df).mark_rect(
        width=20, height=20,
    ).encode(
        x = alt.X('x:Q', scale=xscale),
        y = 'y:Q',
    ).add_selection(
        node_brush
    )

    edges = alt.Chart(edge_df).mark_rule(color='yellow',
    ).encode(
        x = alt.X('x:Q', scale=xscale),
        y = 'y:Q',
        x2 = 'x2:Q',
        y2 = 'y2:Q',
    ).transform_lookup(
        lookup='dst',
        from_=lookup_data
    ).transform_lookup(
        lookup='src',
        from_=lookup_data,
        as_=['x2', 'y2']
    ).transform_filter(
        node_brush
    )

    full_chart = (edges + nodes).properties(
        height=500,
        width=1000,
    )
#----------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    node_df = pd.read_csv("node_df_MWE.csv")
    edge_df = pd.read_csv("edge_df_MWE.csv")
    chart = drawPlot(node_df, edge_df)
    st.altair_chart(chart, use_container_width=True)
```

Comment: Could you include a fully reproducible example including the data so that we can try to figure it out?

Comment: I have provided my data and code via a shared link on Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `fields=['x2', 'y2']`, when you setup the selection. However, interval selections only support the primary x and y encodings at this point, so you would also need to change the selection type to either single or multi, which does makes it a bit hard to hit when clicking but it does select both sources and edges: `node_brush = alt.selection_single(fields=['x2', 'y2'])`.

Maybe the best workaround for you is to create a second edge chart that has the x,y swapped with the x2,y2 in the lookup:

```py
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt


node_df = pd.read_csv("~/Downloads/node_df_MWE.csv")
edge_df = pd.read_csv("~/Downloads/edge_df_MWE.csv")

node_brush = alt.selection_interval()

xscale = alt.Scale(domain=[0, 127])
yscale = alt.Scale(domain=[0.,500])

lookup_data = alt.LookupData(
    node_df, key="id", fields=["x", "y"]
)

nodes = alt.Chart(node_df).mark_rect(
    width=20, height=20,
).encode(
    x = alt.X('x:Q', scale=xscale),
    y = 'y:Q',
).add_selection(
    node_brush
)

edges = alt.Chart(edge_df).mark_rule(color='red',
).encode(
    x = alt.X('x:Q', scale=xscale),
    y = alt.Y('y:Q', scale=yscale),
    x2 = 'x2:Q',
    y2 = 'y2:Q',
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='src',
    from_=lookup_data
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='dst',
    from_=lookup_data,
    as_=['x2', 'y2']
).transform_filter(
    node_brush
)

edges2 = alt.Chart(edge_df).mark_rule(color='red',
).encode(
    x = alt.X('x:Q', scale=xscale),
    y = alt.Y('y:Q', scale=yscale),
    x2 = 'x2:Q',
    y2 = 'y2:Q',
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='dst',
    from_=lookup_data
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='src',
    from_=lookup_data,
    as_=['x2', 'y2']
).transform_filter(
    node_brush
)

full_chart = (edges + edges2 + nodes).properties(
    height=500,
    width=1000,
)
full_chart
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The solution worked. I was hoping to avoid drawing the edges twice since it adds computational burden. I appreciate it.